# Using variables in config.ini property OSGI.bundles

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp

Config.ini file is having the property osgi.bundles which contains the list of plugins that needs to be started while launching my RCP. For Eg.:

```
osgi.bundles=reference\:file\:org.junit_4.8.2.v4_8_2_v20110321-1705/@4,reference\:file\:org.mortbay.jetty.server_6.1.23.v201012071420.jar@4,reference\:file\:org.mortbay.jetty.util_6.1.23.v201012071420.jar@4
```

Clarification :
I need to use the Java variables/Environment variables in the reference of the plugins. So that I can make my RCP more flexible. Please suggest a solution.

I need something like below:

```
osgi.bundles=reference\:file\:{ENV.USERDIR}/org.junit_4.8.2.v4_8_2_v20110321-1705/@4
```

Here when trying the load the bundles, JUNIT bundle should be loaded from the replaced from the environment variable USERDIR as.

```
c:/users/username/org.junit_4.8.2.v4_8_2_v20110321-1705
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Vikram

Comment: The Eclipse code that reads `osgi.bundles` (`org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter`) doesn't support this.

Comment: I have modified the code in EclipseStarter which reads inosgi.bundles. But i am not able to read vaiables. Are you sure if Eclipse starter is running the program after generating the product?

Comment: Well have you built a new version of the `org.eclipse.osgi` plugin containing your modified EclipseStarter and made sure that that plugin is being invoked during startup?

Comment: Yes i have made sure that new version is being used.. Do you have any idea about WebStartMain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is supported in org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_V1.3.0 or higher. You can use the environment variables like

**$variable_name$/bundle-name.jar**.

While parsing the config file, The launcher will substitute the value of the variable and start the bundle from the specified location.